# Magent oupgrade to 2.4.3 stuck in setup:upgrade

Tags: upgrade, magento2.4.3, centos

I am trying to **upgrade magento from 2.2 to 2.4.3**. I am **stuck in setup:upgrade** step. This is running from past 12 hours and is showing Module  'Magento_PurchaseOrder', :-
19:18:14 Module 'Magento_Vault':
19:18:14 Module 'Magento_Paypal':
19:18:14 Module 'Magento_PaypalGraphQl':
19:18:14 Module 'Magento_PaypalNegotiableQuote':
19:18:14 Module 'Magento_PurchaseOrder':

I am not sure whether it is stuck or takes this much time. I don't see anything in the logs. If I scroll up in console I can see the step inside setup:upgrade is "Data install/update:". 
**Can someone suggest is stuck or still running? How can I check if it's running or stuck? Any tables or logs to verifY?**

Comment: Did you find a way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In case the upgrade fails it will display the specific error. In your case, the program is still running. Please wait for the upgrade to complete.
In case if it shows a non-specific error you can go to var/log -> here you can see the files containing the error codes please check each file to know what is happening with the process you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the var/vendor folder existing or not ?

If not then download Magento 2.4.3 and upload vendor folder in var/ directory.

then run again setup:upgrade command it's working.

Answer (score 0):

It took time but this was completed.